# Access Denied For Views

Tags: views

We have a View showing all nodes of type 'member'. We have set permissions to view this node only for authenticated users. If anonymous user tries to access this view then it displays blank page. We expected that it will be redirecting to the page set under 'admin/config/system/site-information' for the 403 page(Access denied), but it is not. It is redirecting if anonymous user tries to access any node instance of 'member' itself but not if the view. How to configure 'Access denied' page for a view? Thank You

Drupal 7.23

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in this case you should set access to the view directly under page access in the view itself (assuming this is a page view). You would select Access > Role > "member" (and any other role that needs access).

Then users who do not have the role "member" should get a 403, and your custom redirect should work.

Comment: Thank You Dave. This worked perfect. Best of luck to you

Comment: Currently, by default in view there is no 403 showing, the view is just not displayed for people that cannot access it.